# JavaFX Subclass pseudoclass

Tags: css, javafx

I wan to make 2 different styles of button in one css. So when creating the second button i added class to it using:

```
close.getStyleClass().add("close-button");
```

so now i can reference this button in css by:

```
.button.close-button
```

But now i dont know how to reference pseudoclasses of button when using the `.close-button` class.

I tried accessing it by

```
.button.close-button:selected
```

or

```
.button:selected.close-button
```

Nor of these seems to work. Is there any way how to do it? Or do i have to create my own pseudoclasses for the `.close-button` class and add and remove them in listeners of the btton in code?

I am creating the button using:

```
Button close = new Button("X");
close.getStyleClass().add("close-button");
close.setOnAction((event) -> {
    ....
});
```

Than i am adding it to the layout:
    HBox hbox = new HBox(rbSelect, label, pane, close);

my css looks like:

```
.button {
   ...
}

.button.close-button {
   -fx-background-color: #E81123;
}

.button:selected.close-button {
   -fx-background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

The button looks like this:
[image: Button not clicked]

When i click on it:
[image]

Seems like nothing happens, when i would expect the button to change color to greenyellow

Comment: I think this should work the first way yo describe. Can you provide a [MCVE] showing this problem?

Comment: Take look at my editted answer.

Comment: Shame on me i figured i out.... all the time i am using wrong subclass...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is necessary, but by convention the pseudo class selector is added after the class selectors:

```
.button.close-button:selected {
   -fx-background-color: greenyellow;
}
```

However there is no `selected` pseudo class for `Button`. It's available for `CheckBox` and `ToggleButton`, but not for regular `Button`s. Pseudoclasses that are available are `:pressed` and `:hover`, [see css reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#button).

You could of course add the pseudoclass yourself, assuming you're using JavaFX 8:

```
PseudoClass selected = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("selected");

close.setOnAction((event) -> {
    ....
    close.pseudoClassStateChanged(selected, true);
});
```